# Update UIBarbuttonItem font when disabled - iOS 11

Tags: ios, fonts, uibarbuttonitem, ios11, xcode9

Upto iOS 10, the font for disabled and enabled uibarbuttonitem remains same, only color differs. But, after i installed my app on device having ios 11, the font for disabled mode get updated(showing system font), whereas in enabled mode it is showing the proper font which i set.

So, for case of iOS 11, How can i set font for disabled mode to keep consistency in the app.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This appears to have changed in iOS 11, at least in my case where I'm using the UIAppearance protocol. Not sure if this is a bug or intentional.

I also found I couldn't mask values together (such as `.normal|.disabled`) as it meant it would only apply the font if the control satisfied *all* states.

So I ended up doing this:

```
for controlState in [UIControlState.normal, UIControlState.disabled, UIControlState.focused, UIControlState.highlighted, UIControlState.selected] {
    barButton.setTitleTextAttributes([NSFontAttributeName: customFontName], for: controlState)
}
```

For updating it everywhere using the UIAppearance protocol:

```
for controlState in [UIControlState.normal, UIControlState.disabled, UIControlState.focused, UIControlState.highlighted, UIControlState.selected] {
    UIBarButtonItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes([NSFontAttributeName: customFontName, for: controlState);
}
```